# how to get name from id selected check box

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have table in modal with action type checkbox

this my result, i can't get name or other data value by that 'id' which already i checked before.

i just want called name n description from table tindakan to put in main table. help me where the wrong code i'v done.

[image]

this is my controller

```
public function get_tindakan(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->status;
    $data = Action::where('id', $term)->get();
    $result['success'] = true;
    $result['result'] = $data->toArray();
    return Response()->json($result);
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
var base_url = '{{ URL::to(' / ') }}';
let _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    var Checkboxes1 = [];
    var idline = $('#idline').val();
    var iduser = {
      {
        Auth::id()
      }
    };
    $("input:checkbox[name='Checkboxes1']:checked").each(function() {
      // if (this.checked == true) {
      var status = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
      let _url = `/get_tindakan/${status}`;
      console.log(status);
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: _url,
        data: {
          'id': status,
          _token: _token
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      })

      $("table#tindakandipilih").append(createTr(status));

      function createTr(status) {
        var tr = '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + status + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + status + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + status + '</td>' +
          '<td style="vertical-align: middle"><label><input type="checkbox" name="gratis"/><span></span></label></td>' +
          '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="flaticon-delete"></i></span></button></td>' +
          '</tr>';
        return tr;
      }
      // }
      // else {
      // var status = status.filter(e => e !== this.value);
      // Checkboxes1 = Checkboxes1.filter(e => e !== this.value);
      // $("table#tindakandipilih").delete(createTr(Checkboxes1));
      // }
      // console.log(idaction, idline, iduser);

    });
  });
});



$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  // count--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  // $("#countChecked").html(count);
});
```

**Modal**

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-borderless cssTable" id=tabel-action>
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">No. Tindakan</th>
        <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">Nama Tindakan
        </th>
        <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">Tindakan</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($tindakan as $action)
      <tr id="row_{{ $action->id }}">
        <td>{{ $action->actioncode }}</td>
        <td>{{ $action->actionname }}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes1"
        class="checkbox" value="{{ $action->id }}" />
        <span></span></label></td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="button1" class="btn btn-danger font-weight-bold" data-dismiss="modal">Pilih</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary font-weight-bold" data-dismiss="modal">Kembali</button>
</div>
```

and this is my main table. if i checked some thing in modal, that data will show in this main table

```
<div class="card card-custom gutter-b">
  <a id="reset-anchor" class="btn btn-success font-weight-bold" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTT">Tambah Tindakan</a>

  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="tindakancheck">
      <table class="table table-hover table-borderless cssTable" id="tindakandipilih">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">No. Tindakan</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">Nama Tindakan</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">Harga</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">Tidak Membayar</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle" scope="col">Tindakan</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <div id="output"></div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are seriously ajaxing once for every checked checkbox?

Comment: @Sajjad, sorry my bad

Comment: @mplungjan thanks edited it for me. i use ajax just to create table by id checked in my modal. after hit submit button, it will send it to main table with data result ajax (name, desc, price etc). but it dosen work, my be bad jquery or controller of mine. hope some body can help to fix

Comment: Perhaps: `const data = {  _token: _token,  $("input:checkbox[name='Checkboxes1']:").map(function() { return { id: this.value, checked: this.checked } }).get() }`